# Qual método do windows pego o Rage de data do calendario quando utilizo dois dígitos na data?

Tags: windows, calendar

Estou tentando achar o método do windows que me permite buscar o ano inicial do Rage do calendário quando utilizo a data abreviada com o ano de dois dígitos: `dd/mm/yy`.

Utilizando o `GetLocaleInfoA` eu consigo pegar o formato de data abreviada com `LOCALE_SSHORTDATE`, a data por extenso com `LOCALE_SLONGDATE`.

Não estou conseguindo achar o método que me retorna o ano inicial.

Comment: Desculpa, mas em qual linguagem você está trabalhando, poderia colocar como tag para que outras pessoas possam te ajudar?

Comment: Olá Ivan, estou  utilizando Delphi e Java, mas como o método é do windows.. o que eu preciso é igual indiferente da linguagem.

Comment: Oi Alini,  talvez esse [link](http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?t=93573) possa te ajudar.